# Where can I find the JDK documentation, and how can I read it offline?

Tags: java, javadoc

I know how to read the Javadoc (JDK documentation) online on a website, but I want to download a copy to my computer so that I can read it offline when no Internet connection is available.

To be clear, I am referring to the *Java® Platform, Standard Edition & Java Development Kit Version x API Specification*.

How can I download the documentation?