# How do i look java doc in mac?

Tags: java, doc

[image]

I want to check Java doc while I'm working on the code, but I don't know how to read it.
Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to go to online documentation? I can see in the screenshot that your IDE is already showing the JavaDoc about `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure whatever tool or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you are using to point it to the Javadoc files.

Likely you have a choice of (A) pointing to a URL for access over the internet, and (B) pointing to a folder where you [downloaded the Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6986993/642706) files to your local computer.