# how can we install Java Api Help in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, api

When i am connected with internet, eclipse internal browser opens that page and when i am not connected with the internet, it can not display the web page. I want the web page to be installed locally on my computer, so that i do not have to worry about internet connection.

I am attaching snapshot of the help that i want available offline.

http://cubixshade.com/newScreen.jpg

Comment: which web page you are talking about ?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the source code for JRE?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Download the javadocs zip file from java website (link for Java 7 docs 
[Here)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html).

Now in ur eclipse go to the `Prefernces`

[image: Go to Preferences]

and choose `Installed JREs` 
[image: Select Installed JREs]

Now if u have multiple JREs installed choose the one which you use and click `Edit`.

> Note that the JRE for which the checkbox is checked is the one which is
>   default, u can over ride the default for a specific project.

[image]

Expand the `lib\rt.jar` as shown below.And select the `Javadoc location` property, click on `Javadoc Location` button
[image]

> NOTE :If u have chosen a JDK (as shown above) then there will automatically be a
>   source attachment.(And u probably wont need a javadoc-api explicitly).But in case of a JRE the source will not be available unless specified manually.(See next image.).In Either case u can attach a javadoc offline.
>   [image]

Now in the javadoc window select `Javadoc in archive` radio button and click on `Browse...`, select the javadoc zip file downloaded earlier
[image]

Click `OK` or `Finish` to close all the open windows (javadoc window, Edit JRE window, and Preferences window)

That's it!! Now u can use the javadoc, Enable the javadoc view in `Window > Show View > Javadoc.`

[image]

Just double click on any class in ur java src file editor and u will see the javadoc for it in the javadoc window as well as in a tool tip. 
[image]

Hope its solved ur problem. Let me know if u have any issues.

Comment: Thanks shams, you images really help me a lot.

Comment: Pleasure.. Hoping to get the bounty ;) :)

Comment: For JRE 1.8... Above procedure was not working initially. 

I had to add the "docs/api" into the "Path within archive" field as seen on the 3rd image above...

Answer (score 3):

- Download the JDK API http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#docs
- Go to the Java Build properties by right clicking on a project and then clicking **properties...**
- Click the **Libraries** tab
  [image: Libraries tab]
- Click on **Javadoc location** for `classes.jar`.
  [image: Javadoc location for classes.jar]
- Click **browse** and select the folder where you downloaded the documentation to. (Choose the API folder for java 6 and java 7).
- Click OK (twice).
- It will now use the offline version.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the java api and use it when you are offline;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#docs

Though I'm not sure how to connect the api with eclipse, there should be some settings for it.

---

edit: you can look at this question for deeper information, there is an answer for eclipse;
[Offline Java Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449558/offline-java-documentation)

Comment: The link you pasted contains only jdk versions/demos etc.. I didn't find any api for eclipse.

Comment: @adn  you want the jdk docs!  Download them and point eclipse at them via the build settings

Comment: BTW I don't want jdk docs !! just I refereed link n gave comments

Comment: @adn_295, what I understand from `api` is this, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ and you can download this via given link; under the `Java SE 7 Documentation` section.